# TFS doesn't show new files in pending changes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

Whenever I add new file to my folder, I am expecting it to be shown in Pending changes include items but TFS does not show them as pending changes.

To check in new files I have to navigate to Source Control Explorer-> new file and add it to source control.

Is there any setting or way to automatically show new file in pending changes.

Comment: How do you add file to your folder? In Visual Studio or Windows Explorer? If added in VS it should appear in the pending changes, I've done that exact thing many times...

Comment: I am adding files in VS Code or in folder directly some times.

Comment: Also, what kind of file is it? Simple code file or something else. Some file types are excluded from source control. When you right-click on a folder within your solution explorer and click on Add, new file should immediately appear in the list with a plus sign in front of it and in the Team Explorer pending changes as well...

Comment: Not sure about VS Code but I assume it should be the same experience. As long as you use the Add option from the context menu of the folder in the Solution Explorer it should be added to list of files immediately...

Comment: Yes when I add file from Visual Studio it shows but that is not the case when I add it in VS Code.